# Cloud Data Fusion - enabling Wrangler

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

I am unable to enable the wrangler from the Cloud Data Fusion console. I do get to a screen but it looks nothing like what is in the tutorials or documentation.

When I enable the wrangler, I get to a screen as shown in the attached image.

This happens in the developer version of Cloud Data Fusion, however, the wrangler screen comes up correctly under the Basic edition.

[Wrangler screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6yIm.png)

Answer (score 0):

This only means two things,

1. Your url to wrangler seems to have a workspace ID. When backend gets unknown workspace id it responds with an error. Do you happen to open this from within the pipeline studio (from wrangler transform)?
2. If not #1 then your wrangler system app seems to be having issue. Did you had to start the wrangler app from UI (Click on "Enable Wrangler" button?). Wrangler and AppFabric logs would be helpful to debug this issue.

Will update this answer based on the logs and errors you are seeing.

Comment: Looks like the Developer version might have a bug, the Basic edition works ok. Thanks.